# Prove that maximising $\frac xy$ is equivalent to maximising $x-y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Given $(x,y) \in \mathbb R_{\gt0}^2$, I want to prove (or disprove) that maximising $\frac x y$ is equivalent to maximising $x-y$, that is:

$$\arg \max_{x,y}\left(\frac x y\right) = \arg \max_{x,y}\left(x-y\right)$$

How to do that analytically?

Comment: They are not equivalent; compare $(2,1)$ and $(15,10)$.

Comment: Ok but that's like throwing numbers and seeing if it works  - what if the counterexample  were more hidden? How would I find it analytically?

Comment: Suppose $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are two points with $x_1/y_1<x_2/y_2$; try to prove that $x_1-y_1<x_2-y_2$ and see where you fail. Or vice versa.